# jQuery determine which <option> is selected

Tags: jquery

I Have my select box:

```
 <select name="in_slider" id="in_slider">
     <option value="1">Yes</option>
     <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
 </select>
```

As you can see there are two of them and one is already selected (It needs to be defaulted to this selection so that it is processed correctly when passed to the database)

Underneath I have another select and options, exactly the same code just with a different name and id.

When the user, clicks the first select option and changes the value to Yes(1) I need the second select to hide()

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedoption = $('#in_slider').val();
    var valueistrue = "1";

    if (selectedoption == valueistrue) {
        $('#selectboxtwo').hide();  
    }
});
```

But to no avail. :(

Because there is already a value selected it runs the moment the page loads and I cant let that happen as initially the second select needs to be visible.

JsFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/WwnbG/

Comment: `$('#in_slider option:selected')`

Comment: @kirilloid - Why not an answer? Looks sound! :)

Comment: I tried that - It runs when the page is loaded and I think that is because there is already a selected option.

Comment: COuld u maybe put it in jsfiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WwnbG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7MBz/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $( "#in_slider").change(function() {

    var selectedoption = $('#in_slider').val();

    var valueistrue = "1";

    if (selectedoption == valueistrue) {
        $('#in_stock').hide();

    }
});



});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `change` function of first select option and then write your code inside that.

```
$('#in_slider').change(function () {
   var selectedoption = $('#in_slider option:selected').val();
   var valueistrue = "1";

   if (selectedoption == valueistrue) {
      $('#selectboxtwo').hide();
   }
});
```

[<kbd>JS Fiddle Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/B82P3/1/)

[<kbd>Your Fiddle Example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/WwnbG/14/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  var selected = $('#in_slider option:selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#in_slider option:selected').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value:

```
var selected_value = $("#in_slider option:selected").val();
```

or to get the text of the selection:

```
var selected_text = $("#in_slider option:selected").text();
```

I've editted your JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WwnbG/13/

```
<div class="section-price-ch-third">
    <p>Display in slider?</p>
    <select name="in_slider" id="in_slider">
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="section-price-ch-third">
    <p>In Stock?</p>
    <select name="in_stock" id="in_stock">
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#in_slider").change(function(){

    var selectedoption = $("#in_slider option:selected").val();
    var valueistrue = "1";

    if (selectedoption == valueistrue) {
        $('#in_stock').hide();
    }else{
        $('#in_stock').show();
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedoption = $('#in_slider :selected').val();
    var valueistrue = $('<checkbox name> :checked').val(); ex: $('input[name=check] :checked').val()

    if (selectedoption == valueistrue) {
       $('#in_slider option[value=0]').hide();
    }
});
```

Your query: "I need the second select to hide()". do you mean the second select **option** should be disabled/hidden?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the whole select and its options. Please refer up to post for new added link to jsfiddle